# Update multiple records via checkboxes and dropdown in Rails.

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu

Let's say I have several Posts in an index.

I need to be able to select multiple of them via checkboxes, and then select an action to be done on all selected records (delete, toggle a boolean field in the database to make them all public or private, some other arbitrary method on all of them, etc) using a dropdown with the options and a 'submit' button?

What is the best and simplest way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to define a method in your controller against your submit action and then loop individually on each item to update each record

```
def update_multiple
  @products = Product.find(params[:product_ids])
  @products.each do |product|
    product.update_attributes!(params[:product].reject { |k,v| v.blank? })
  end
  flash[:notice] = "Updated products!"
  redirect_to products_path
end
```

Comment: Any tips for what my form/table/dropdown would look like? This definitely seems to be a good controller for it.

Comment: if you are asking about your table schema then it depends upon your need else kindly explain sorry i didn't get it

Comment: No, nothing with my schema. I'm wondering what the view would look like.

Comment: you said yourself you have several posts in index, from your question what it would come to my mind is, there are multiple checkboxes (which you also mention) user would select them and submit the form, and at controller end your would receive it in params and do update them

Comment: i hope it would answer your question